# Какую структуру хранения данных в MySQL выбрать для опросника?

Tags: mysql, дерево, nested-sets

- У нас есть последовательная форма, типа визарда.
- На каждом этапе, есть вопрос, и есть варианты ответов, в виде радио
  кнопок.
- В зависимости от нажатия той или иной кнопки, на следующем шаге
  появляется тот или иной вопрос.

Подойдет ли для хранения таких данных `Nested Sets`?
Или есть что то, более подходящее?

Comment: Nested set, конечно, ориентирован на работу с деревьями, да вот беда - вы ни одной операции, выполнение которых облегчает эта структура хранения, не описываете. Да и нет их в вашей предметной области. Так что простого M:N self-join с отдельной таблицей связи более чем достаточно.

Comment: @Akina Можно расшифровать M:N self-join? Лучше конечно схематично, если не затруднит...

Comment: *Можно расшифровать M:N self-join?* `CREATE TABLE questions (id PK, ...)` `CREATE TABLE answers (id PK, question_id NOT NULL FK questions (id), next_question_id NULL FK questions (id))`